# How to update an array of an object in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

I want to update isFilter to true if indexName is 'bcd'.

```
attr: [
{
  indexName: 'abc',
  isFilter: false,
},
{
  indexName: 'bcd',
  isFilter: false,
},{
  indexName: 'bcd',
  isFilter: false
}
]
```

I tried,

```
<document>.updateMany({}, 
{ $set : {
   "attr.$[elem].isFilter" : true
} },
{
  arrayFilters: [{
         "elem.indexName" : "bcd"
   }],
  multi: true,
});
```

Did I do something wrong? It's not working.

Comment: You are missing close curly braces. `{ $set : { "attr.$[elem].isFilter" : true } },`

Comment: I mistakenly left to close while posting. This is not the problem.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pxjYxGTH8FZ

Comment: Can you enter better data to mongoplayground?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/iHclp7MOyfP Here it is. I am working on mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Use "attr.indexName" for search query.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/W50Abcj7zPM

```
 db.collection.update({
      "attr.indexName": "Mama"
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "attr.$.isFilter": true,
      },
    },
    {
      "multi": true,
      "upsert": false
    })
```

Comment: It works but for only the first matching. I want this to work for all the object in an array.

Comment: Did you add multi true option?

Comment: You can use updateMany too.